# How to enforce the type of an array to be passed down to a child component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

My issue here is that I have a `DataTable` component that is defined like this

```
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  rows: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  },
  columns: {
    type: Array as PropType<IColumn[]>,
    required: true
  }
});
</script>
<template>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(row, i) in rows" :key="i">
      <td v-for="column in columns" :key="column.name">
        <slot :name="`cell.${column.name}`" :row="row" :value="row[column.name]" /">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```

This component can accept **arrays of any type** for the `rows` property and is used like this

component1

```
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  myTypeArray: {
    type: Array as PropType<MyOtherType>,
    default: () => []
  }
});
</script>
<template>
  <DataTable :rows="myTypeArray" :columns="[{ name: 'someOtherProperty' }]">
    <template #cell.someOtherProperty="{ row }">
      {{ row.someOtherProperty }}
    </template>
  </DataTable>
</template>
```

component2

```
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({
  myTypeArray: {
    type: Array as PropType<MyType>,
    default: () => []
  }
});
</script>
<template>
  <DataTable :rows="myTypeArray" :columns="[{ name: 'someProperty' }]">
    <template #cell.someProperty="{ row }">
      {{ row.someProperty }}
    </template>
  </DataTable>
</template>
```

The type of the array is properly set here but the DataTable component doesn't know about it and considers the array as `any[]` so in my component's template, when I use `row.someProperty` in component2 and `row.someOtherProperty` in component1, it doesn't know that `row` is of type `MyType` or `MyOtherType` and considers it as `any` instead.
How to make sure that DataTable knows about the type without having to do `(row as MyType).someProperty` everywhere? Is there a way to use a `DataTable<T>` component that has the `rows` property type `as PropType<T[]>`?

Is it even possible? I **don't want to** have to have this as it would be hard to maintain. I really want the parent component to provide the type to the DataTable component as we do with `<T>` for interfaces or classes or even to have it enforced by the parent in a different way if possible

```
rows: {
  type: Array as PropType<MyType[] | MyOtherType[] | MyLastType[]>,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question.

Since Vue 3.3, we can now define generic components. See https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3#generic-components

The solution here is to define DataTable as a generic component, like this

```
<script setup lang="ts" generic="T">
defineProps({
  rows: {
    type: Array as PropType<T[]>,
    required: true
  },
  columns: {
    type: Array as PropType<IColumn[]>,
    required: true
  }
});
</script>
<template>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(row, i) in rows" :key="i">
      <td v-for="column in columns" :key="column.name">
        <slot :name="`cell.${column.name}`" :row="row" :value="row[column.name]" /">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```

When using the DataTable component, the type of `row` will now be inferred properly and TypeScript will be able to check any type error in the template and know that, in component1, `row.someOtherProperty` exists and in component2, `row.someProperty` exists.